# Windows Azure Cannot Connect to Azure DB

Tags: sql, azure

Using a worker role locally, I cannot connect to my database. I receive this error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)

Here is what I've done:

1. I have created a firewall rule for my IP
2. I cannot connect to my database locally through SQL Management Studio.
3. In production on the server, it works.

Connection string

Server=tcp:SERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYDB;User ID=MYUSER;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I turned off Norton Internet Security and my firewall and I am OK. I had to turn off the firewall running on my machine. Go to settings > network > intrusion protection > off

Answer (score 0):

I use a connection string similar to the following:

```
data source={your_server_prefix_here}.database.windows.net;initial catalog=MYDB;persist security info=True;user id=MYUSER;password={your_password_here}!;
```